# How to sum up the prediction vectors of a keras model into a single vector

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have 2 keras models.
The first gets as input a string and gives
a prediction for example, five classes.

In the second model I want to use this output.
However, the output of the first model should be summed up into a single output for multiple inputs.

I want single prediction for the sum of all entered strings and not a prediction for each entered string.

```
model1 = tf.keras.Sequential()
model1.add(Input(shape=(len(inputs[0]),), dtype=tf.float32))
model1.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model1.add(Dense(len(helper_classes), activation='softmax'))

model2 = tf.keras.Sequential()
model2.add(model1)
model2.add(Dense(16))
model2.add(Dense(len(classes), activation=tf.nn.softmax))
model2.layers[0].trainable = False
model2.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model2.summary()
```

For explanation: the strings are preprocessed to a float vector.

Actual output of model1:
Input: "Hello","World", ...
Output: [0.2, 0, 0, 0.8, 0],[0, 0, 0.4, 0, 0.6], ...

What i need:
Input: "Hello","World", ...
Output: [0.2 + 0.0 + ... , 0 + 0.0 + ... , 0 + 0.4 + ... , 0.8 + 0.0 + ... , 0 + 0.6 + ...]

[Image of model1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiuQV.png)
[Image of model1 after adding Reduction Layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0elz.png)

**Solution**
Okay I solved it now. My first mistake was that I summed up on axis 1. What I could fix with the help of vlad.
The second mistake was that I did not keep the dimensions with keep_dims = true.

The solution was to insert a lambda layer in the second model which basically does what Vlad and Thibault proposed:

```
model2 = tf.keras.Sequential()
model2.add(model1)

model2.add(Lambda(lambda x: K.sum(x, axis=0,keepdims=True)))

model2.add(Dense(16))
model2.add(Dense(len(classes), activation=tf.nn.softmax))
model2.layers[0].trainable = False
model2.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `tf.reduce_sum()`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
output = tf.Variable([[0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0],[0.0, 0.0, 0.4, 0, 0.6],])
reduced = tf.reduce_sum(output, axis=0)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(reduced.eval())
    # [0.2 0.  0.4 0.8 0.6]
```

To use it within `Keras` define a custom layer like this:

```py
from tensorflow.keras import layers

class ReductionLayer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ReductionLayer, self).__init__()

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.reduce_sum(inputs, axis=0)
```

and add it to your `Sequential()` model:

`model.add(ReductionLayer())`

Comment: Looks like a good approach I've just tried it. Shape (None, 5) becomes (5,). But if i call "model1.predict(np.array(keywords))" I get the following error: "could not broadcast input array from shape (5) into shape (19)" (length of keywords is 19)

Comment: The code that you posted has plenty of mistakes and won't be able to run(e.g. this is not valid syntax `model2.add(len(classes), activation=tf.nn.softmax))`). If you want me to help you fix your code and provide the actual values of shapes that you have (e.g. the value of `len(classes)`).

Comment: i just added a picture of the model structure vlt helps that. and yes it's maybe not runnable it's more like pseudo code

Comment: You're asking a complete different question now. Without seeing the code I won't be able to help you.

Comment: it is relatively extensive. which part do you need

Comment: I've answered your specific question. What you're asking now is something completely different. Try asking another question but before, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Answer (score 1):

If i understand well your problem, all you need is to sum your last Dense layer of model1.
You can achieve that by unsing Keras backend Sum :

```
keras.backend.sum(x, axis=None, keepdims=False)
```

You can found doc here : https://keras.io/backend/#sum

Comment: My last dense layer in model1 have already shape (None, 5). Adding this sum function will give the output the shape (None,)

Comment: `axis=None` does reduction over all dimensions. Read the link you posted yourself.

Comment: Yeah ok my bad, I misunderstand